# How can explode a words from field with multiple values?

Tags: php, foreach, autocomplete

I have this table: TABLE_ELEMENTS, with the name ELEMENTS, i have a multiple values inside, see image.

[image]

[image]

This is the php and return the results from autocomplete request.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/include/autocomplete.php?type=mauto_complete",
```

First i call this..

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && in_array($_GET['type'], $arr_action)) $type=$_GET['type']; 

if($type == "mauto_complete") {
    require_once $config_abs_path."/autocomplete/autocomplete.php";
    if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $term = escape($_GET['term']);
    $response = mauto_complete::getAutocomplete($term);
    echo json_encode($response);
}

}
```

And this is the secondauto.php file
    function getAutocomplete($term) {

```
    global $db;
    global $config_table_prefix;
    global $crt_lang;

    $elements=$db->fetchRow("select Distinct `elements` from TABLE_ELEMENTS where `elements` like '$term%' limit 10");
    $elements_array = explode("|", $elements);
    return $elements_array;
}
```

I have write this after select

```
$elements_array = explode("|", $elements);
```

Ok the request is working fine, but in autocomplete results when i type the word Building i take no words.
But when i type the first word of the elements ( Apartment ) i take all words.

The words is not uniqe

Comment: `$term%` is a *starts with*, for a *contains* use `%$term%`

Comment: That's right ok now i take the results for every word, but now if i type buildi... other words it is stay open in autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to this is to add a `|` to the left of the field, then search that. This ensures that an element containing the search doesn't get matched.

```
select
    Distinct `elements`
from
    TABLE_ELEMENTS
where
    lower(CONCAT('|', `elements`)) LIKE lower('%|$term%')
```

However, you're probably looking for something else. Below is how I'd approach it. I couldn't figure out what library you were using for your connection, so you may have to change a little bit for it to work for you.

```
function getAutocomplete($name, $term)
{
    // make sure you escape the string to avoid SQL injection
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);

    // make the searches case-insensitive
    $term = strtolower($term);

    // fetch the valid elements for the field and split them using explode
    $elements = $db->fetchRow("SELECT `elements` FROM `TABLE_ELEMENTS` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    $elements_array = explode('|', $elements);

    // make an array to save the matching elements
    $filtered = array();

    // iterate over each element to check for a match
    foreach($elements_array as $element)
    {
        // check to see if the beginning of the element starts with the search term
        if(strpos(strtolower($element), $term) === 0)
        {
            // add it to the filtered array
            $filtered[] = $element;
        }
    }

    // return the matching results
    return $filtered;
}
```

Then to use it, specify what field you want to autocomplete for:

```
print_r(getAutocomplete('Property Type', 'B'));

// Outputs: Array
// (
//     [0] => Building
//     [1] => Bungalow
//     [2] => Business
// )
```

To make your existing code to use it, change your JavaScript to match the following. You'll need to change name depending on what field you're autocompleting.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/include/autocomplete.php?type=mauto_complete&name=Property%20Type"
});
```

Then update the file where you call the getAutocomplete function:

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && in_array($_GET['type'], $arr_action)) $type=$_GET['type']; 

if($type == "mauto_complete") {
    require_once $config_abs_path."/autocomplete/autocomplete.php";
    if(isset($_GET['term']) && isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $term = $_GET['term'];
        $response = mauto_complete::getAutocomplete($name, $term);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont take any results without $elements_array = explode("|", $elements); and with this i take all result but again show me all words again

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Okay. Now if I search for b, do you want your getAutocomplete() function to return building, bungalow and business?

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Okay, I've updated my answer. MySQL isn't very good at splitting strings, so it's typically done in PHP. If you want to use MySQL to filter the elements, you'll want to change your database structure.

Comment: Thnx for your help but select Distinct `elements` from TABLE_ELEMENTS where `elements` like '%$term%' limit 10 is missing and without this the autocomplete can not make the requests this code not show any result i change it but again nothing

Comment: It won't show any results because you need to modify how you call the function. The reason it no longer uses `Distinct elements` is because MySQL doesn't see the items separated by `|` as individual items.

Comment: I have update my answer and how the autocomplete call php check it

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos I've updated my answer to include the changes you need to make.

Comment: OK Ryan Pendleton your answer is completely corect this is the working php now, but with one problem.. See my answer below to check it!

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Sorry, it should be fixed now. I updated the foreach loop in the `getAutocomplete` function.

Comment: All corect again but the same with the second word, When i Type 2 word like Ap is gone i don't understand what is the problem your code is perfect, only this, one need to fix. And i have update my answer below the name 'name' it is not needed anymore. This: print_r(getAutocomplete('Property Type', 'B')); need to use somewhere?

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Oh man, sorry. I didn't completely fix it. Remove the `[0]` and you should be good to go. You don't need to use the print_r(...) anywhere, as that was just for debugging. And if you don't mind elements from different fields mixing, then you're correct, you don't need the name.

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Glad I could help. If you feel I have solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try use like this to get all possible results

```
$elements=$db->fetchRow("select distinct `elements` from TABLE_ELEMENTS where lower(`elements`) like lower('%$term%') limit 10");
```